# How would I make a door "stun" a player

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone, minecraft-education-edition

I am playing Minecraft Education Edition, and I want to know if it is possible for the door to stun a player. For example if there are 5 players I want 1 of them to be able to be stunned by the door. What I want to happen is when 1 of the 4 players closes a door and if the other 1 player is close enough they will be stunned. Summary, there are 5 players and only 4 of them can close doors. If 1 of the four players closes a door while the 1 player is close enough, how would I stun that player?

Comment: Maybe applying a high level of slowness in a certain radius?

Comment: You could apply a slowness potion using an execute command that checks if someone is inside of a door, but it will probably require plugins to detect door closing/opening.

Comment: you could try using lingering potions of slowness with high potency with short durations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a repeater to detect if the door is closed and have the repeater power a command block with the command `/effect (insert name of the person you want to stun) blindness (duration of effect) 1 true`